# TypeError and ValueError while training model with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a convolutional model with keras. And I have encountered two errors that I have never encountered earlier and I couldn't find a solution to them online. Here is the entire error traceback output:

> WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
>       W0617 03:18:36.916876 139928036104064 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:74:
>   The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.
>
> ```
> W0617 03:18:36.956070 139928036104064 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From
> ```
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:517:
>   The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.
>
> ```
> W0617 03:18:36.965062 139928036104064 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From
> ```
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4185:
>   The name tf.truncated_normal is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.random.truncated_normal instead.
>
> ```
> W0617 03:18:37.005445 139928036104064 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From
> ```
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:174:
>   The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.
>
> ```
> W0617 03:18:37.006534 139928036104064 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From
> ```
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:181:
>   The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.
>
> ```
> W0617 03:18:39.945574 139928036104064 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From
> ```
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1834:
>   The name tf.nn.fused_batch_norm is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.nn.fused_batch_norm instead.
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:19: UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API:
> ```
>
> `Model(inputs=Tensor("in..., outputs=Tensor("ac...)`
>       W0617 03:18:40.237022 139928036104064 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py:790:
>   The name tf.train.Optimizer is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer instead.
>
> ```
> W0617 03:18:40.366632 139928036104064 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py:1250:
> ```
>
> add_dispatch_support..wrapper (from
>   tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in
>   a future version.
>       Instructions for updating:
>       Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>       =================================================================
>       input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 28, 28, 1)         0
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 36)        180
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 28, 28, 36)        144
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 28, 28, 36)        0
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 18)        2610
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 28, 28, 18)        72
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 28, 28, 18)        0
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 9)         657
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 28, 28, 9)         36
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 28, 28, 9)         0
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 7056)              0
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 345)               2434665
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 345)               0
>       =================================================================
>       Total params: 2,438,364
>       Trainable params: 2,438,238
>       Non-trainable params: 126
>       _________________________________________________________________
>       Train on 3450000 samples, validate on 345000 samples
>       Epoch 1/100
>       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>       /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tables/array.py in **getitem**(self, key)
>           660             # First, try with a regular selection
>       --> 661             startl, stopl, stepl, shape = self._interpret_indexing(key)
>           662             arr = self._read_slice(startl, stopl, stepl, shape)
>
> ```
> 7 frames
> TypeError: Non-valid index or slice: [1484419, 2231123, 3092786, 1496830, 493122, 736949, 1199629, 328357, 931000, 2946100, 415877,
> ```
>
> 1421951, 3421223, 2238167, 2940723, 1437219, 1839514, 2746665,
>   3359532, 3268348]
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tables/leaf.py in _point_selection(self, key)
>     579             # handle negative indices
>     580             idx = coords < 0
> --> 581             coords[idx] = (coords + self.shape)[idx]
>     582 
>     583             # bounds check
>
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,) (4,)
> ```

The shape of training data is (3450000, 28, 28, 1) and training labels is (3450000, 345).  I have trained similar models before but have never encountered such errors like non-valid index slice and operands could not be broadcast together. I am using Google Colab for the training. The code for training is:

```
def create_model():
  inp = Input((28,28,1))
  conv1 = Conv2D(36,(2,2),padding="same",kernel_initializer="glorot_normal")(inp)
  batch1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
  act1 = Activation("relu")(batch1)

  conv2 = Conv2D(18,(2,2),padding="same",kernel_initializer="glorot_normal")(act1)
  batch2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
  act2 = Activation("relu")(batch2)

  conv3 = Conv2D(9,(2,2),padding="same",kernel_initializer="glorot_normal")(act2)
  batch3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
  act3 = Activation("relu")(batch3)

  out = Flatten()(act3)
  out = Dense(345)(out)
  out = Activation("softmax")(out)

  model = Model(input = inp, output = out)
  adm = optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.02)
  model.compile(optimizer=adm,loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.summary()

  return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
  model = create_model()
  history = model.fit(x = train_X, y = train_Y, batch_size = 20, epochs = 100, validation_data = (eval_X, eval_Y))
```

Comment: have you tried to plot the images of non-valid index in your train_X?

Comment: @meowongac what do you mean by plotting them? display each of the images?

Comment: @meowongac I displayed those images, they are fine.

Comment: Looks like compatibility issue as there are a lot of deprecation error. I think you are using TF 2.0 with deprecated functions. I haven't used 2.0 yet so I am not sure.

Comment: @Anakin but the same model works if I create a random numpy array of same shape and fit that

Answer (score 0):

Add this to start of your code Specify the TensorFlow version since default in colab is now Tensorflow V2.0

%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.**version**)